# How does auto boxing/unboxing work in Java?

Tags: java, autoboxing, unboxing

Since JDK 5.0, auto boxing/unboxing was introduced in Java. The trick is simple and helpful, but when I started testing different conversions between wrapper classes and primitive types, I get really confused how the concept of auto boxing works in Java. For example:

**Boxing**

```
int intValue = 0;
Integer intObject = intValue;
byte byteValue = 0;
intObject = byteValue; // ==> Error
```

After trying different cases (`short`, `long`, `float`, `double`), the only case which is accepted by the compiler is when the type of the value on the right of affectation operator is `int`.
When I looked inside the source of `Integer.class` I found that it implements only one constructor with `int` parameter.

So my conclusion is that the concept of auto boxing is based on constructor implemented in the wrapper class. I want to know if this conclusion is true or there is another concept used by auto boxing?

**Unboxing**

```
Integer intObject = new Integer(0);
byte byteValue = intObject; // ==> Error (the same Error with short)
int intValue = intObject; 
double doubleValue = intObject;
```

My conclusion about unboxing is that the wrapper class gives the value wrapped by the object in the corresponding type (`Integer` ==> `int`), then the compiler use the usual rules of converting primitive types (`byte` => `short` => `int` => `long` => `float` => `double`).
I want to know if this conclusion is true or there is another concept used by auto unboxing?

Comment: Have you read the Java Language specification sections on autoboxing? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7

Comment: `byte byteValue = intObject;` - you do realize that's an error regardless of whether `intObject` is an object or a primitive type, right?

Comment: I thinks the compiler use the method `Integer.intValue()` to unbox the wrapped value, is this correct?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thanks so much your link is really helpful, it answers my question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When in doubt, check the bytecode:

```
Integer n = 42;
```

becomes:

```
0: bipush        42
2: invokestatic  #16                 // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
5: astore_1
```

So in actuality, [`valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28int%29) is used as opposed to the constructor (and the same goes for the other wrapper classes). This is beneficial since it allows for caching, and doesn't force the creation of a new object on each boxing operation.

The reverse is the following:

```
int n = Integer.valueOf(42);
```

which becomes:

```
0: bipush        42
2: invokestatic  #16                 // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
5: invokevirtual #22                 // Method java/lang/Integer.intValue:()I
8: istore_1
```

i.e. [`intValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#intValue%28%29) is used (again, it's analogous for the other wrapper types as well). This is really all auto(un)boxing boils down to.

You can read about boxing and unboxing conversions in [JLS §5.1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) and [JLS §5.1.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8), respectively.

Comment: In the fact i'm java beginner (i don't understand bytecode), so when i started reading a chapter of autoboxing it gives just some examples of limitations of auto boxing/unboxing and not all rules, then i tried to parse all cases, and  want to confirm if my comprehension of this concept is corrected or not.

Comment: @NarutoBijuMode I think your main misconception was about *how* the (un)boxing happens. As I pointed out in the answer, it just comes down to the invocation of two specific methods; `valueOf()` and `intValue()` (respectively).

Comment: Thanks for help :), i think i'm the stupid one who asked an explanation which i will not understand in this moment (i should learn more about java). Thanks.

Comment: I thought implicit boxing/unboxing was expensive and never really recommended. I think Joshua Bloch might have said that? So is it now acceptable to use implicit conversion and not have to explicitly call `valueOf()` and `intValue()`?

Answer (score 4):

This confusion can be cleared by using a switch of javac **-XD-printflat** which is very helpful in cases such as this one. So to unravel the mystery of boxing and unboxing you can write a simple program like following :

```
import java.util.*;

public class Boxing{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Double d1 = 10.123;
    Float  f1 = 12.12f;
    Long   l1 = 1234L;
    Integer i1 = 55555;
    Short   s1 = 2345;
    Byte    b1 = 89;

    double d2 = d1;
    float  f2 = f1;
    long   l2 = l1;
    int    i2 = i1;
    short  s2 = s1;
    byte   b2 = b1;
  }
}
```

and now we compile the above file as:

**javac -XD-printflat -d src/ Boxing.java**

output of this command is a java file with all the syntactic sugar (**Generic types, enhanced for loop and in this case boxing-unboxing etc**) removed. following is the output

```
import java.util.*;

public class Boxing {

    public Boxing() {
        super();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double d1 = Double.valueOf(10.123);
        Float f1 = Float.valueOf(12.12F);
        Long l1 = Long.valueOf(1234L);
        Integer i1 = Integer.valueOf(55555);
        Short s1 = Short.valueOf(2345);
        Byte b1 = Byte.valueOf(89);
        double d2 = d1.doubleValue();
        float f2 = f1.floatValue();
        long l2 = l1.longValue();
        int i2 = i1.intValue();
        short s2 = s1.shortValue();
        byte b2 = b1.byteValue();
    }
}
```

this is how java does boxing unboxing. using valueOf and ***Value methods.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code as an example of auto un-boxing:

```
System.out.println('b'+ new Integer(63));
```

Here's a breakdown of how the above code is compiled:

Step 1: Object Integer 63 is instantiated and then AUTO-UNBOXED to int 63

```
new Integer(63)
```

Step 2: char 'b' is converted to numeric value i.e. 98

Step 3: the two values are added: 98+63

Step 4: Output is 161

Answer (score 0):

**Auto boxing and auto unboxing**

Auto boxing means when we try to assign a primitive data to a object type it automatically converts itself to the object type.that process called auto boxing.. and when a object type converts to the primitive type its called unboxing...try to understand it  from following examples.

```
class Demo{
public static void main(String args[]){
    int x=100;

    //Integer iob=x; //Illegal jdk1.4
    Integer iob=Integer.valueOf(x); //Legal at JDK1.4 =>Boxing

    Integer iob2=x; //Legal JDK1.5 - Autoboxing
    System.out.println(iob2);
}
```

}

another example for auto boxing

```
class Demo{
public static void main(String args[]){
    Integer iob=new Integer(100);    
    int x;
    x=iob; //Legal => auto unboxing
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

}

example for auto unboxing

```
class Demo{
public static void main(String args[]){
    Integer iob=new Integer(100);
    int x=iob; //Auto unboxing ==>Assignment

}
```

}

thank you..