# How is unboxing done in Java?

Tags: java

I know how boxing is done. For example, when you write  `Integer a = 4`, `Integer.valueOf(int)` is being called. Likewise, can i see the implementation code for unboxing as well?

Update : It is answered in the suggested question.

Comment: Both the answer there and the one given here explain that unboxing is typically done with `intValue()` (or the corresponding method for that particular type). It also links to the very specific chapter in the JLS. There's nothing else to it.

Comment: The linked JLS points to the right info. But its in the comments, not in answers. I think this should not be marked as duplicate, or may be this answer needs to be added there.

Comment: I don't understand what you're not seeing. It's right there in the body of the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22648696/438154). _The reverse is the following: `int n = Integer.valueOf(42);` which becomes [...], ie. `intValue()` is used_.

Comment: My bad. I got confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases,`intValue()` gets called to get the primitive value.

```
Integer a= new Integer(4);
int val = a.intValue();
```

Like the integer, all the wrapper classes have this method to get it's primitive value.