# Why primitive types allow in collection through for each loop?

Tags: java, collections, primitive

```
List<Integer> l=new LinkedList<Integer>();

// Now add elements to the Link List
l.add(2);
l.add(3);
l.add(4);

for (int b:l) {
    System.out.print(a + " ");
}
```

Comment: they are converted to instances of Wrapper objects. what makes you think the for:each loop has any impact on this?

Comment: It is called "autounboxing". See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22648627/how-java-auto-boxing-unboxing-works.

Answer (score 6):

The `List` in your snippet doesn't hold primitive `int`s. They're [autoboxed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/autoboxing.html) to `java.lang.Integer`s when you add them to the list and unboxed back to `int`s when you retrieve them from the list (e.g., by iterating over it).