# Autoboxing with varargs

Tags: java

```
class MyClass{
    static void aut(int i) {}
    static void aut(Integer i) {}

    static void vararg(int... ia) {}
    static void vararg(Integer... ia) {}

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        aut(1); // compiles successfully 
        vararg(1); // The method vararg(int[]) is ambiguous for the type MyClass
    }
}
```

I am not able to understand why `vararg(1)` is throwing an error.

Comment: It could be either one of them

Comment: @ifly6 `aut(1)` compiles successfully but compiler has problems with unboxing/autoboxing with vararg. Why???

Comment: The error I get from IntelliJ is that both methods match.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Same error is thrown when we use `vararg(Integer.valueOf(1))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22648627/how-java-auto-boxing-unboxing-works

Comment: try this      Integer[] intArr = {Integer.valueOf(1)};
      vararg(intArr);. Compiler is getting confused whether to use int[] or Integer[] it seems

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most specific method should be choosen and that should the method with single int parameter and not varargs.

Looks like the bug of Java not completely resolved although they marked it as resolved.

[JDK-6886431 : Handling of "most specific" varargs method inconsistent with JLS](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6886431)

**A DESCRIPTION OF THE PROBLEM :**

> When invoking a method with the following overloaded signatures, I expect an ambiguity error (assuming the arguments are compatible with both):

```
int f(Object... args);
int f(int... args);
```

> javac treats the second as more specific than the first.  This behavior is sensible (I prefer it), but is inconsistent with the JLS (15.12.2).