# Why is Integer a=10 a valid statement in java?

Tags: java, class, types, wrapper, primitive-types

As far as I know, Integer is a wrapper **class** for int. So an object must be created for initializing value of a.

```
Integer x=new Integer(10);
```

But `Integer x=10;` seems to work perfectly. Can someone please explain how?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How java auto boxing/unboxing works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22648627/how-java-auto-boxing-unboxing-works)

Comment: Yes I have understood it clearly, thankyou so much.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to autoboxing.

Autoboxing is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper classes. For example, converting an int to an Integer, a double to a Double, and so on. If the conversion goes the other way, this is called unboxing.

See docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Answer (score 2):

[Autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) freely converts between primitives and their wrapper classes in most contexts and is described in
[JLS, §5.1.7. Boxing Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html).

> Boxing conversion converts expressions of primitive type to corresponding expressions of reference type. Specifically, the following nine conversions are called the boxing conversions:
> [...]
>
> - From type `int` to type `Integer`

> At run time, boxing conversion proceeds as follows:

> - If `p` is a value of type `int`, then boxing conversion converts `p` into a reference `r` of class and type `Integer`, such that `r.intValue() == p`
>   [...]

> If the value p being boxed is an integer literal of type int between -128 and 127 inclusive (§3.10.1), or the boolean literal true or false (§3.10.3), or a character literal between '\u0000' and '\u007f' inclusive (§3.10.4), then let a and b be the results of any two boxing conversions of p. It is always the case that a == b.

Answer (score 1):

## Auto-boxing

[*Boxing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_(object-oriented_programming)#Boxing) is the process of wrapping a primitive value as an object of a class of the equivalent type. [*Unboxing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_%28object-oriented_programming%29#Unboxing) refers to the opposite direction, going from object to primitive.

For example, an `int` primitive can be boxed as a `Integer`.

[*Auto-boxing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_(object-oriented_programming)#Autoboxing) is the Java compiler doing this wrapping/unwrapping behind the scenes.

Auto-boxing simplifies life for us app programmers. In our daily work we can often think of the primitive and object as being the same. But know that they are *not* the same. There are some situations where a programmer must be aware of whether a primitive or an object is in hand. Enjoy the convenience of auto-boxing, but do not operate blindly.

### Your example code

In your example:

```
Integer x = 10 ;
```

…the `10` is parsed by the compiler as a `int` primitive. Then, via auto-boxing, that primitive is wrapped as an `Integer` object. The instantiation of the `Integer` object is happening behind the scenes, transparently.  A reference to that object is then assigned to the variable named `x`.

### More info

See the links above to Wikipedia. And see the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) by Oracle.

### Pure OOP

Understand that Java is *not* purely [object-oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). If it were, we would have no primitives; we would have only objects. And therefore we would have no boxing.

So why did the designers of Java include primitives, adding this wrinkle of complexity to our lives? To facilitate porting code from [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)) and other [C-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_C-family_programming_languages) languages. Easy  porting was a crucial requirement at the time of Java’s invention.

Comment: The only catch I'd add here is, that it still doesn't mean that `int` and `Integer` are same, implying, that whenever you need your field to be serializable, you wouldn't want to have a primitive there.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri I’ll emphasize that a bit more.