# new Integer(1) returns a different id with 1

Tags: java

Suppose the following assignment:

```
jshell> int a = 1;
a ==> 1
jshell> int b = 1;
b ==> 1
jshell> var c = new Integer(1);
c ==> 1
```

Check their id with System.identityHashCode:

```
jshell> System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(1))
1938056729

jshell> System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(a))
1938056729

jshell> System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(b))
1938056729

jshell> System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(c))
343965883
```

C returns a different ID, the "1" which c references is different from that of a and b?

Comment: `a` and `b` are primitives. `c` is an object. Recommend searching "objects vs primitives" or something along those lines

Comment: java primitives have wrapper classes which are not the same as the pimitive types themselves

Comment: new Integer allocates a new Integer. [autoboxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22648627/how-java-auto-boxing-unboxing-works) uses [Integer.valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)), which may cache values

Comment: Just to be clear, since it's been implied by comments and the answer, but not stated: `a` and `b` do not have an identityHashCode, they are primitives not Objects. So they are getting autoboxed to an Integer.

Answer (score 3):

That is expected. The first three lines are boxing conversions and [Integer::valueOf is specified to return the same instances for the inclusive range -128 to 127.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-int-)

You explicitly used new for c. That will always create a new instance which returns a different hash code. If you replace `new Integer(1)` with `Integer.valueOf(1)` it will return the same hash code as the others.